# Is there a way to narrow a cast with the same bit pattern in VB?

Tags: vb.net, casting

In Java, when a primitive is cast into a primitive with fewer bits, the exact value is not passed along, but a new interpretation of the remaining bits.  In VB it appears that a conversion looks for a similar value to pass along and gives an error when it can't.

I'm interested in retaining the exact bit pattern.  Without string manipulation (which I can do, I'm just hoping for a more efficient/quicker way), is there a way in VB to narrow the cast by simply dropping the extra bits? Along the same lines, is it possible to a signed to an unsigned (and vice versa) with the same exact bit pattern?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the BitConvert Class.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint16%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB when you make a narrowing cast, you will get an exception if the value is out of range. There isn't really any way around that. Neither `CType`, `DirectCast` or `Convert.ToXXX` methods let you convert it without checking.

What you can do, is to drop the extra bits before you do the conversion. Example:

```
Dim a As Integer = 123456789
Dim b As Byte = a And Byte.MaxValue
Console.WriteLine(b)
```

Output:

```
21
```

This works for converting between signed/unsigned types too, at least from signed types to unsigned types. Example:

```
Dim a As Integer = -128
Dim b As UInteger = a And UInteger.MaxValue
Console.WriteLine(b)
```

Output:

```
4294967168
```

---

Note: If you have implicit conversions turned off in the compiler settings, you would need to do an explicit conversion:

```
Dim b As Byte = CType(a And Byte.MaxValue, Byte)
```

Comment: That is the kind of magic I'm looking for.  It looks like that should work with a narrowing cast.  I forgot to mention (edited in now) that I also want to do direct conversions between signed and unsigned with the same bit pattern.  I tried that with this trick and it didn't work.  Any suggestions for that?  It doesn't have to be a one formula fit all deal.  I think that getting to that point is a victory.

Comment: @TomK: Converting between signed/unsigned works too. I added an example above.

Comment: I am trying to see it in action with

Comment: It appears to work very well going from a signed to an unsigned.  But going from an unsigned to signed doesn't get the right maximum value for the mask because the max for SByte is 0111 1111, unless I just had a typo somewhere.  I think I can work with this.  I love bitwise operators. lol Thank you very much.

Comment: Guffa, I just noticed a typo on my part.  I meant to say that getting to THIS point is victory.